# How to use JSF's selectOneMenu?

Tags: jsf, jsf-1.2, selectonemenu

I'm having problems in using JSF's selectOneMenu.

I have been trying somethings like the ones below, but no one seems to work...

Can someone help me?

JSP:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{myBean.listCats.desc}" id="desc">
    <f:selectItems value="#{myBean.selectAllCats}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

myBean:

```
(...)
    public Collection<SelectItem> selectAllCats() throws (some exceptions...){  
        this.listCats = this.controller().selectAllCats();
        Collection<SelectItem> toReturn = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();  

        for( int i = 0; i<this.listCats.size(); i++){  
          toReturn.add( new SelectItem( this.listCats.get(i).getCod(), this.listCats.get(i).getDesc()));  
        }
        return toReturn;
    }
(...)
```

Just a bit more info:

```
List<Cats> listCats = new List<Cats>();
//-------------------------------------
class Cats{
    private int cod; // both with getters and setters
    private String desc;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

---

Edit:

I forgot to say that I keep getting the following error:

> '#{myBean.selectAllCats}' Property 'selectAllCats' not found on type
>   path.to.myBean

Comment: You forgot to describe "doesn't work" in detail. Please describe the problem in developer's perspective, not in enduser's perspective. By the way, have you looked at the tag info page of the `[selectonemenu]` tag which you put on the question yourself? Hover it with your mouse until a black box shows up and then click therein the *info* link.

Comment: I forgot to describe the error I was getting! Sorry about that!
I didn't know about the tag info page, and it was really very helpful.
The 'Dynamic list' section explains everything I need to know.
Thanks BalusC, that will be very helpful in the future!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> '#{myBean.selectAllCats}' Property 'selectAllCats' not found on type path.to.myBean

For properties, you should be providing a valid getter method. You didn't have any one, as the exception is trying to tell you. A valid getter method for `selectAllCats` property should look like this.

```
public Collection<SelectItem> getSelectAllCats() {
    return selectAllCats;
}
```

Note that performing business job in a getter is bad practice. You should be doing that in the (post)constructor of the bean.

#### See also:

- [Our `selectOneMenu` wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/selectonemenu/info)

Answer (score 1):

```
 List<Cats> listCats = new List<Cats>();
```

And

```
 myBean.listCats.desc
```

List does not have a property called `desc`. `Cats` have, but `listCats` is a list.

BTW: Better if your class names are singular, unless they represent a group.

Comment: The real name is Cat, you are right!
It was an error committed while transcribing the code!

Answer (score 0):

The method

```
public Collection<SelectItem> selectAllCats() throws (some exceptions...)
```

returns a `Collection`, which is not supported by `<h:selectOneMenu>` in JSF 1.2.

This method should return `List`, `Map` or `Object[]` so its sign should be rewritten like this:

```
public List<SelectItem> selectAllCats() throws (some exceptions...)
```

Apart from that, you'll face another problem with your JSP at this line:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{myBean.listCats.desc}" id="desc">
```

`listCats` is a `List` composed by `Cats` (which should be renamed with `Cat`) and this list doesn't have a `desc()` method. This line also should be modified like this (modify according your needs:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{myBean.listCats.get(0).desc}" id="desc">
```

Comment: In my case, "#{myBean.listCats.get(0).desc}" would not help because I need it to be dynamic! thanks!

Comment: Then you should add a new method to your bean and use it in your JSP according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know about the tag info page, and that's why I didn't search my answer there.

You can find it in this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/tags/selectonemenu/info

Or:

> By the way, have you looked at the tag info page of the
>   [selectonemenu] tag which you put on the question yourself? Hover it
>   with your mouse until a black box shows up and then click therein the
>   info link. – BalusC

The answer I was looking for is in the Dynamic List section of that info page,
which is quoted below for further reference on the matter:

> Dynamic list
>
> You can use  to display a list which is dynamically
>   populated in the backing bean. You can use
>   javax.faces.model.SelectItem to represent a pair of item value and
>   label.
>
> View:

```
<h:form>
     <h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.selectedItem}">
         <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="-- select one --" />
         <f:selectItems value="#{bean.availableItems}" />
     </h:selectOneMenu>
     <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{bean.submit}" /> </h:form>
```

> Model:

```
private String selectedItem; // +getter +setter private
 List<SelectItem> availableItems; // +getter (no setter necessary)

 @PostConstruct public void init() {
     availableItems = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
     availableItems.add(new SelectItem("foo", "Foo label"));
     availableItems.add(new SelectItem("bar", "Bar label"));
     availableItems.add(new SelectItem("baz", "Baz label")); 
 }
```

> The availableItems can also be a SelectItem[]. If you omit the item
>   label
>
> > and thus can use the item value as both option value and option label,
> >     then you can also use a List or String[] instead.

```
private String selectedItem; // +getter +setter private List<String>
 availableItems; // +getter (no setter necessary)

 @PostConstruct public void init() {
     availableItems = Arrays.asList("foo", "bar", "baz"); 
 }
```

Thanks!